# Why I can only update a user's data in ASP.Net Core with Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I was testing my application and I saw that I can only update the information of a single user and not that of the others, the application does not give me an error message or anything, it only reloads the page and the data does not reach the database data, whereas with a single user this does not happen.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UniJobs.Data;
using UniJobs.Models;

namespace UniJobs.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<Usuarios> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Usuarios> _signInManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<Usuarios> userManager,
        SignInManager<Usuarios> signInManager,
        ApplicationDbContext context,
       IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        this._context = context;
        this._webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Imagen de perfil")]
        public IFormFile InputImagen { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "¿Quién Soy?")]
        public string QuienSoy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sobre mis habilidades")]
        public string SobreHabilidades { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sobre mis aptitudes")]
        public string SobreAptitudes { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Provincia")]
        public int? Provincia { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Mi universidad")]
        public int? MiUni { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de nacimiento")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    private async Task LoadAsync(Usuarios user)
    {
        var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

        user.ID_Uni = _context.ListaEstudiantesUniversidades.Where(U => U.FK_UsuarioID == user.Id)
                              .Select(U => U.FK_UniversidadID).FirstOrDefault();

        Username = userName;

        Input = new InputModel
        {
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
            Provincia = user.FK_ProvinciaID,
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
            MiUni = user.ID_Uni,
            QuienSoy = user.QuienSoy,
            SobreHabilidades = user.SobreHabilidades,
            SobreAptitudes = user.SobreAptitudes
        };
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        ViewData["FK_ProvinciaID"] = new SelectList(_context.Provincias, "ProvinciasID", "Provincia");
        ViewData["Universidad"] = new SelectList(_context.Universidades, "UniversidadesID", "NombreUniversidad");

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }
        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
        if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
        {
            var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
            if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
            {
                StatusMessage = "Unexpected error when trying to set phone number.";
                return RedirectToPage();
            }
        }

        if (Input.InputImagen != null)
        {
            //Save image to wwwroot/image
            string wwwRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string ImageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Input.InputImagen.FileName);
            string ExtensionImage = Path.GetExtension(Input.InputImagen.FileName);
            user.ProfileImage = ImageName = ImageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ExtensionImage;
            string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/UsersImages/Users/", ImageName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await Input.InputImagen.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            //Insert record
        }

        if (Input.MiUni != _context.ListaEstudiantesUniversidades.Where(U => U.FK_UsuarioID == user.Id)
                                   .Select(U => U.FK_UniversidadID).FirstOrDefault())
        {
            var UniID = _context.ListaEstudiantesUniversidades.Where(U => U.FK_UsuarioID == user.Id)
                                .Select(U => U.ListaEstudiantesUniversidadesID).FirstOrDefault();

            var StudentUni = await _context.ListaEstudiantesUniversidades.FindAsync(UniID);

            _context.ListaEstudiantesUniversidades.Remove(StudentUni);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var Uni = _context.ListaEstudiantesUniversidades.Add(new ListaEstudiantesUniversidades
            {
                FK_UniversidadID = Input.MiUni.Value,
                FK_UsuarioID = user.Id
            });
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        if (Input.FirstName != user.FirstName)
        {
            user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
        }
        if (Input.LastName != user.LastName)
        {
            user.LastName = Input.LastName;
        }
        if (Input.BirthDate != user.BirthDate)
        {
            user.BirthDate = Input.BirthDate;
        }
        if (Input.Provincia != user.FK_ProvinciaID)
        {
            user.FK_ProvinciaID = Input.Provincia;
        }
        if (Input.QuienSoy != user.QuienSoy)
        {
            user.QuienSoy = Input.QuienSoy;
        }
        if (Input.SobreHabilidades != user.SobreHabilidades)
        {
            user.SobreHabilidades = Input.SobreHabilidades;
        }
        if (Input.SobreAptitudes != user.SobreAptitudes)
        {
            user.SobreAptitudes = Input.SobreAptitudes;
        }

        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code of the Identity Index class

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in `PostAsync` and (if you are using Visual Studio) use Steps (F10) to find where the program exits.

Comment: I did that, but immediately, the program goes the line return Page (); in the second if statement

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` is false, so it will directly return Page () . which indicates some explicitly specified validation rules were broken during the model binding process. You may check it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already solved the problem. basically the problem was inside the <select> </select> tags, the <option> </option> tag was causing problems when sending the form data to the controller, because nothing was being sent trying to send a string instead of a int.